# How to check if a user exists in the model that I made in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm making login page and data is already saved in model I made and not usercreateform... and instead of searching the user in my model(UserAuthentication), it searches in Users ...

**view.py**

```
def loginpage(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
       username = request.POST.get('username')
       password = request.POST.get('password')
       user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
       if user is UserAuthentication: #UserAuthentication is my model where data is stored
           login(request, user)
           return redirect('index')
       else:
           messages.warning(request, "Username OR Password is incorrect!")
           return redirect('login')
   else:
       return render(request, "HTML/login.html", context={})
```

**login.html**

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
                        {%csrf_token %}

                        <input
                            class="text"
                            type="text"
                            name="username"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            required=""
                        />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <input
                            class="text"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            required=""
                        />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                        {%for message in messages%}
                        <p id="messages">{{message}}</p>
                        <br />
                        {% endfor %}
                        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" />
                    </form>
```

**models.py**

```
class UserAuthentication(models.Model):
    username  = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,verbose_name="Username",error_messages={'required':'Username already exists'})
    email     = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name=" Email")
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=50 ,verbose_name="Password")
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=50 ,verbose_name="Confirmaition Password")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Can you share your model(s)?

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file, you need to specify which user model you want to use in the project.

Add this line to the `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<app_name>.UserAuthentication'
```

Of course, change `<app_name>` with the name of the app in which `UserAuthentication` model is defined.

Further, it is not so easy to customize the user model in Django. I strongly recommend you to take a look at the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). You may find it confusing, then you can search `custom user in Django` on Google. There are lots of great tutorials.

Comment: I did mention it in settings.py `AUTH_USER_MODEL= 'mylogin.UserAuthentication' ` but it shows an error which is  `AttributeError: type object 'UserAuthentication' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS' `

Comment: Hi, I mentioned this issue in my answer.  The problem you recently wrote is unrelated to this question. Indeed, it is a new question. For example, you need to inherit [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) not `models.Model`.